# dbml file - create database

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a database using `BA.dbml` file (Linq to Sql).  I know I have to create `DataContext` and create the database. But I don't know how to it. Do I have to create `DataContext` in the `BA.cs` file.

It might be redundant post, I am sorry for that.

Comment: I suggest you read a tutorial on linq2sql http://www.sidarok.com/web/blog/content/2008/04/21/a-brief-introduction-to-linq-to-sql.html

Comment: By convention, and if you created the DataContext correctly, you should be able to access it by calling BADataContext.  e.g., var db = new BADataContext();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See these blog posts showing how to create dbml file and then create database from that dbml file.

http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2008/11/21/linq-to-sql-dbml-more-than-just-for-accessing-a-db.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420.aspx