# create database from DBML file?

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

How to create database from Linq to Sql DBML file.

I have created a project with LinQ to SQL Database file. I want to create 20 tables so I would like to Generate a database from DBML file.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944447/dbml-file-create-database