# How can I insert .dbml file to db without having to create new tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio

I have designed a database with tables inside, then used Entity Framework to connect them in Visual Studio. Now the server crashed I lost everything. But my `.dbml` file is still in the application.

**Question**: How can I insert `.dbml` file to db without having to create new tables in SQL Server?

The file looks like this:

```
<Table Name="dbo.tblUserLogin" Member="tblUserLogins">
    <Type Name="tblUserLogin">
      <Column Name="UserID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsDbGenerated="true" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="Username" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(20)" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="Passwords" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(20)" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="IsAdmin" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Association Name="tblUserLogin_tblEmployee" Member="tblEmployees" ThisKey="UserID" OtherKey="UserID" Type="tblEmployee" />
    </Type>
</Table>
```

Comment: You should have kept backups. The dbml file is your *data model*, you don't insert it anywhere. You can generate a database from it using Visual Studio. It won't be the same as the original though - dbml isn't a replica of your database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dbml file - create database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944447/dbml-file-create-database)

Comment: You should use Visual Studio's Database Project to reverse engineer the *and* version the database.

Comment: `.dbml` is for **Linq-to-SQL** - not Entity Framework (that would be a `.edmx` file - if any at all)